# What does "tvb(offset):string()" mean?

Tags: lua, wireshark

this days,I'm learning how to use Lua to write WireShark plugin.But I don't know what the mean of `tvb(offset):string`. Why is wrong of use `tostring(tvb(offset))`?  thank you for your answer

```lua
function weibo.dissector(tvb, pinfo, tree)
    local proto_type = tvb(23, 1):uint();
    if(proto_type ~= 0x06) then
        return
    end

    local offset = get_payload_offset(tvb, proto_type)
    local data = tvb(offset):string();
    local i, j = string.find(data, "weibo")
    if(i) then
        pinfo.cols.protocol = weibo.name
        local subtree = tree:add(weibo, tvb(offset+i-1))
        subtree:append_text(", ptn_pos: " .. i .. "-" .. j)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tvb is a [Testy Virtual Buffer](https://wiki.wireshark.org/LuaAPI/Tvb#Tvb).

> A Tvb ("Testy Virtual Buffer") represents the packet's buffer. It is
>   passed as an argument to listeners and dissectors, and can be used to
>   extract information (via TvbRange) from the packet's data. Beware that
>   Tvbs are usable only by the current listener or dissector call and are
>   destroyed as soon as the listener/dissector returns, so references to
>   them are unusable once the function has returned.

A call as tvb(offset) returns a [TvbRange](https://wiki.wireshark.org/LuaAPI/Tvb#TvbRange)

> A range of bytes within a Tvb that is used to extract data. A TvbRange
>   is created from `tvb:__call()` or `tvb:range([offset] [,length])`.

Remark: 
tvb is a Lua table. If you call it like `tvb()` the `__call()` [metamethod](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4) is invoked.

https://wiki.wireshark.org/LuaAPI/Tvb#tvb:__call.28.29

> **tvb:__call()**
>
> **Description**
>
> Creates a TvbRange from a subset of this Tvb. Same as tvb:range().
>   Cannot be directly called.
>
> **Returns**
>
> userdata : The new TvbRange

One of TvbRange's many methods is [tvbrange:string()](https://wiki.wireshark.org/LuaAPI/Tvb#tvbrange:string.28.29)

> **tvbrange:string()**
>
> **Description**
>
> Gets a string from the TvbRange
>
> **Returns**
>
> string : The string, containing all bytes in the TvbRange including
>   all zeroes (e.g., "a\000bc\000")

tostring() on the other hand is one of Lua's standard functions.

From https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-tostring

> Receives a value of any type and converts it to a string in a
>   human-readable format. (For complete control of how numbers are
>   converted, use `string.format`.) If the metatable of v has a `__tostring`
>   field, then tostring calls the corresponding value with v as argument,
>   and uses the result of the call as its result.

As tvb implements a [__tostring()](https://wiki.wireshark.org/LuaAPI/Tvb#tvb:__tostring.28.29) `tostring(tvb)` would return the return value of that metamethod.

> **tvb:__tostring()**
>
> **Description**
>
> Gets a string representation of the Tvb. Cannot be directly called.
>
> **Returns**
>
> string : The string representation